# My data not reaching to the backend node server from react server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, express-validator

my Signup.js file from where the request is initiating,

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import isEmail from 'validator/lib/isEmail';
import isEmpty from 'validator/lib/isEmpty';
import equals from 'validator/lib/equals';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { showErrMsg,showSuccessMsg } from '../Helpers/messages.js';
import { showLoading } from '../Helpers/loading';
import { signup }   from '../../api/auth';
import './SignUp.css';

const SignUp = () => {
   // filled this for testing purpose 
    const[formData,setFormData] = useState({

        username: 'shivshankar',
        email:'shivshankarkumar.pusa@gmail.com',
        password:'1234',
        password2:'1234',
        successMsg:false,
        errorMsg:false,
        loading:false,
    });
    const { 
        username,
        email,
        password,
        password2,
        successMsg,
        errorMsg,
        loading,
    } = formData;


const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(isEmpty(username) || isEmpty(email) || isEmpty(password) || isEmpty(password2)){
            setFormData({
                ...formData,errorMsg : "All fields are Required"
            })
        }else if(!isEmail(email)){
            setFormData({
            ...formData , errorMsg : "Invalid Email"
            })
        }else if(!equals(password,password2)){
            setFormData({
                ...formData , errorMsg: "Passwords do not Match" 
            })       
        }else{
            const { username , email , password} = formData; 
            const data = { username , email , password};
            setFormData({
                ...formData,
                loading : true,
            })

            signup(data)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log("Axios signup success",response);
                    setFormData({
                        username:"",
                        email:"",
                        password:"",
                        password2:"",
                        loading:false,
                        successMsg:response.data.successMessage
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("Axios post error : " , err);
                    setFormData({...formData, loading : false});
                });
        }
    }
```

my auth.jjs file from the axios post request is generating

```
import axios  from 'axios';

export const signup = async (data) => {
    const config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'applicaion/json',
        },
    };
    console.log(data);
    const response = await axios.post('/api/auth/signup', data, config);
    

    return response;
};
```

now in server side server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const connectDB = require('./database/db');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/auth',authRoutes);

// app.post('/api/auth/signup',(req,res) => {
//     console.log("inside signup");
//     // res.send("api/auth/signup");
// });

connectDB();


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening to port ${port}`));
```

auth.js file for authRoutes`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { signupValidator, validatorResult } = require('../middleware/validator');


router.post('/signup', signupValidator, validatorResult);



module.exports = router;
```

my validator.js file

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

exports.signupValidator =  [
    check('username').not().isEmpty().trim().withMessage('All fields are required'),
    check('email').isEmail().normalizeEmail().withMessage('Invalid Email'),
    check('password').isLength({ min : 6 }).withMessage('Password must be 6 character long'),
];

exports.validatorResult = (req, res, next) => {
    
    // console.log("request body" ,req.body);
    const result = validationResult(req);
    const hasErrors = !result.isEmpty();
    // console.log(result);
    if(hasErrors){
        const firstError = result.array()[0].msg;
        console.log("has errors",hasErrors);
        console.log("result",result);

        return res.status(400).json({
            message : firstError,
        });
    }
   next(); 
};
```

the data is being sent from front-end axios, but the data is not reaching to the back-end node server,

when i  `console.log(req.body)` or `console.log(data)` it says **undefined**.

i am stuck here, can anyone please help me??
get this output in the console.

```
[0] result Result {
[0]   formatter: [Function: formatter],
[0]   errors:
[0]    [ { value: undefined,
[0]        msg: 'All fields are required',
[0]        param: 'username',
[0]        location: 'body' },
[0]      { value: undefined,
[0]        msg: 'Invalid Email',
[0]        param: 'email',
[0]        location: 'body' },
[0]      { value: undefined,
[0]        msg: 'Password must be 6 character long',
[0]        param: 'password',
[0]        location: 'body' } ] }
[0] POST /api/auth/signup 400 34.535 ms - 37
```

[image: I get this in console.log() from frontend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your auth.js file, you have set the Content-Type headers incorrectly it should be `application/json` & not `applicaion/json`

```
import axios  from 'axios';

export const signup = async (data) => {
    const config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json', //this should be application/json
        },
    };
    console.log(data);
    const response = await axios.post('/api/auth/signup', data, config);
    

    return response;
};
```

Comment: Thanks man, it was a silly mistake. now working fine. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to `require` the routes after your `app.use(bodyParser.json());` statement

So move `const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');` to after `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: I added it and still got undefined.

Comment: I think I got the correct answer now see my updated answer

Comment: i tried that also, still not getting the data, i don't understand why the data is not coming from frontend.

Comment: What do you get back from your `console.log(data)` in ` auth.js` in the front end?

Comment: i added a pic please check

Comment: the 400 bad request i am sending, from the server, but it always says all fields are required, but all fields are filled.

Comment: (Hi Shmili, just a quick aside. You don't need to add "hope this helps" and other chatty material to your posts. Every answer author hopes their material helps, and thus it is redundant, in the same way as greetings, discussions about the weather, signatures, etc. Technical writing is preferred here. Thanks!)